# How to use load method if table has two primary keys in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am creating a table with two primary keys. The first one is `id(Integer)` and second one is `email(varchar2(50))`.
  My mapping file contains

```
<hibernate-mapping package="suri.sahasra">
    <class name="Person" table="PERSONS">
        <composite-id name="pkField" class="PKField">
            <key-property name="personId" column="person_id"/>
            <key-property name="email" column="email"/>
        </composite-id>

        <property name="firstName" column="first_name"/>
        <property name="lastName" column="last_name"/>
        <property name="age" column="age"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I am trying to select data using load method, but it's raising a typeMisMatch Exception.
My load function is:

```
Person p1=(Person) ss.load(Person.class,new Integer("1"));
System.out.println(p1.getFirstName());
System.out.println(p1.getLastName());
System.out.println(p1.getAge());
```

How do you retrieve data if the table contains two primary keys. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use

```
Person p1=(Person) ss.load(Person.class,new PKField("1","email"));
```

and PKField must implement .equals() and hashcode() methods,
hibernate relies on  these methods to cache and compare the data.

Answer (score 2):

Create an instance of `PKField` and pass it to load() method.

**NOTE**

Make sure your composite key class satisfies the conditions specified [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/components.html#components-compositeid)

- It must implement java.io.Serializable.
- It must re-implement equals() and hashCode() consistently with the database's notion of composite key equality.

Answer (score 0):

A composite-id means that records are identical if *all* parts of the composite id match. That is, the rows

```
ID  |  EMAIL
----+-------------------
1   |  xyz@somewhere.com
1   |  xyz@elsewhere.com
```

represent *different* objects to hibernate. You therefore need to pass *all* parts of the composite key to `load(...)` to identify the object that should be loaded.

If your intention is that the id by itself uniquely identifies a record, and the same for email, declare one as identifier and the other as [natural-id](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-naturalid). You might have to use queries to get the entity by natural-id (not sure, I never use them myself).